# error to generate build: [vite:load-fallback] Could not load

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

The problem seems to be that I set `baseUrl` in **TypeScript** and `paths`(`alias`).

### config of typeScript

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "screens/*": ["./src/screens/*"],
      "components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    }
```

for it to work i also had to configure **Vite** in: `vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      screens: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/screens'),
      components: 'src/components',
    }
  }
})
```

when using

```
npm run build
```

generated the following error:

```
[vite:load-fallback] Could not load src/components/tables/MainTable (imported by src/screens/Home.tsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\proyect-test\src\components\tables\MainTable'
error during build:
Error: Could not load src/components/tables/MainTable (imported by src/screens/Home.tsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\proyect-test\src\components\tables\MainTable'
```

This project is small and used as an example

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to the following:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      screens: '/src/screens',
      components: '/src/components',
    }
  }
})
```

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9712

Comment: yes and it didn't work

Comment: You should reopen that issue or raise a new one with a minimal repo then.